# Why do I get an error when trying to create a Windows 7 Enterprise VM in Azure DevTest Labs?

Tags: windows, azure

I've been trying to create a VM in *Azure DevTest Labs* using the only available *Windows 7 Enterprise* base image.

[image: This is the error I get]

Unfortunately, the "Failed" status does not provide further details.

[image: These are the VMs characteristics]

NAT protocol / Port to connect : Private
Size : Basic_A3
Operating system : Windows
Base : Windows 7 Enterprise N with SP1 (x64)
Expiration date : No expiration

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

When I tried the same, I got the same error like below:

[image]

The size of virtual machine  `Basic_A3` is not supported to base Windows 7 Enterprise N with SP1 (x64) try to use different size like `Standard_B2s` .

Now when I deploy virtual machine in *DevTest Labs* lab using `Standard_B2s` It created successfully like below:

[image]

[image]

***Reference***:

[Create and add a virtual machine to a lab - Azure DevTest Labs | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devtest-labs/devtest-lab-add-vm)